Importing DXF-Files in QGIS, weird text-angles
I try to load dxf-files in QGIS.
If I open a file in AutoCAD, I can see the textes with a correct angular (you can see it in the image). In QGIS I can successfully load that file, but the angles are not correct (they all have no angle at all).
Does anyone know how to get the correct angles in QGIS?
Good:

So far not so good:


I found a solution by myself: It works with the QGIS-Plugin "Another DXF importer".
